# CPU 100% most of the time - maybe a cron problem?

Tags: cron, performance, resources

e are running shop on Magento 2.4.3-p1 with 50 000 SKUS, about 800 categories and 5 language mutations. About 65000 users and 80 000 sessions monthly.

We are using cloudways server: 32GB RAM 8 core processor 640 GB storage

The CPU seems to be in peaks many times. We are not even running crons every minute, but every 5 minutes. But lot of our crons (for example full page cache) are missed all the time. THe developers from Amasty advised us to change crons to run every minute, do you think the server specs are good enough for this change? I am attaching screenshot of the CPU usage, about 80% of the time it is OK (under 50%), but then there are peaks few times a day when it jumps to 100% or 90%+..[image]

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables; B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) STATUS; not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS; G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So far I think your specs are okay. Could these peaks coincide with customer activity? You say most of the time (80%) everything is okay and CPU usage is under 50%.

If it was the cron job, there would be more daily fluctuations. Try running htop cmd and take a look at what happens during those peaks.

Here is an article to better understand the htop cmd.

https://support.cloudways.com/en/articles/5120765-how-to-monitor-system-processes-using-htop-command